# display xml using linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

```
MessageBox.Show("Hi");

string xml = @"<Table>
                 <Product>
                   <Product_id>1</Product_id>
                   <Product_name>Product 1</Product_name>
                   <Product_price>1000</Product_price>
                 </Product>
                 <Product><Product_id>2</Product_id><Product_name>Product 2</Product_name><Product_price>2000</Product_price></Product>
                 <Product><Product_id>3</Product_id><Product_name>Product 3</Product_name><Product_price>3000</Product_price></Product>
                 <Product><Product_id>4</Product_id><Product_name>Product 4</Product_name><Product_price>4000</Product_price></Product>
               </Table>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Product_id"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Upon button click only `Hi` MessageBox is displayed. The elements are not displayed.

Comment: The code is ok (displays 1 to 4). Are you sure you really look in the console ? What if you replace Console.Write by MessageBox.Show (like for "Hi") ?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments in Form1.cs .... I used MessageBox.Show(element); to display the element .. But it is throwing an error.. Help me with proper usage form. I am very much new to c#

Comment: Simply explained, you have to call element.Value rather than element, which is an object (XElement), unknown by "MessageBox.Show". Console.WriteLine is more permissive.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(element.Value); this worked .. thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome :). In addition to Linq to XML I suggest you to look more thoroughly what's console and where its message are supposed to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. The values will be shown in the console.

```
 MessageBox.Show("Hi");
            string xml = @"
            <Table>
                <Product>
                    <Product_id>1</Product_id>
                    <Product_name>Product 1</Product_name>
                    <Product_price>1000</Product_price>
                </Product>
            <Product><Product_id>2</Product_id><Product_name>Product 2</Product_name><Product_price>2000</Product_price></Product>
            <Product><Product_id>3</Product_id><Product_name>Product 3</Product_name><Product_price>3000</Product_price></Product>
            <Product><Product_id>4</Product_id><Product_name>Product 4</Product_name><Product_price>4000</Product_price></Product>
            </Table>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Product_id"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
            }

            Console.Read();
```

You should call `Console.WriteLine(element.Value);`

Comment: not working. nothing gets displayed after Hi message box

Comment: @Sherin Mathew > I think OP doesn't see Console at all, as I told in my first comment.

Comment: @DhanushD > As I have asked previously, the question is WHERE do you expect to see it ? Have you understood what is "Console" ???